# Magento 2.2.2 Xdebug

Tags: magento2.2, xdebug

I'm trying to debug magento 2.2.2 with xdebug via PhpStorm. When I'm trying to set points in index.php - it works perfectly, but when I'm going to debug some custom or core files Xdebug is not going through that files but if I using die() in those files it works.

It looks like it using php 5.6 instead of 7.0 for xdebug, but in phpstorm everything looks properly.

I'm using this settings:

http://joxi.ru/12ME989I4YoZG2
http://joxi.ru/gmvnBdBCxVEkjm
http://joxi.ru/Vm6LBMBtx95GGA
http://joxi.ru/GrqZ7E7tNjEXVm
http://joxi.ru/Dr8ZBlBtk16G92

Please, help me to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: http://joxi.ru/v29aBEBfGnPER2

Comment: please upload these images to stack. your image hosting provider is not worksafe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable xdebug in your php.ini like this:

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

Make sure you have it enabled in php7.0 and not php5.6

I'm using nginx and php-fpm so on my computer they are located her:

```
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
/etc/php/5.6/fpm/php.ini
```

Don't forget to restart php after you have done your changes

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```